# Symfony 4.1 - Disable SQLFilter in a Twig_Extension

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, twig

I’m experiencing a hard-to-debug issue. I try to disable a doctrine `SQLFilter` within a `\Twig_Extension` yet the filter is still applied on the next query.

I did the same kind of code in a controller and the filter is disabled well.

Here are the relevant parts of the Twig function:

```
/**
 * @return array|\Twig_Function[]
 */
public function getFunctions()
{
    return [
        new TwigFunction('hreflang', [$this, 'hreflang'], ['is_safe_callback' => true, 'is_safe' => ['html']]),
    ];
}

/**
 * Builds and returns the hreflang of a page.
 *
 * @param string                 $locale
 * @param TreeNodeInterface|null $contentObject
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function hreflang(string $locale, TreeNodeInterface $contentObject = null)
{
    // Deactivate the doctrine filter
    if ($this->em->getFilters()->isEnabled('locale_filter')) {
        $this->em->getFilters()->disable('locale_filter');
    }

    // Query the ORM for fetching the translated url.
    // This is the part where the SQLFilter should be deactivated but is not.
    $url = $this->getTranslatedUrl($locale, $contentObject);

    // Reactivate the doctrine filter.
    $this->em->getFilters()->enable('locale_filter');

    // ... Builds and returns the hreflang, no relevant code.
}
```

This piece of code use to run like a charm on a 3.4 application, I’m now working on a 4.1.4

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you actualy call the function `hreflang` inside a template?

Comment: I do, yes. At the top of my base template (in the header).